# Error with complex Factory with Factory Girl Rails on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm using the FactoryGirl gem to create a the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  conta_origem = FactoryGirl.create(:conta_pessoa_fisica)
  conta_destino = ''
  tipos = LogTransacao.tipos.keys
  params = { conta_origem: conta_origem, conta_destino: conta_destino, tipo: tipos[0] }
  codigo_transacional = LogTransacaoHelper::Gerador.codigo_alphanumerico(params)

  factory :log_transacao_carga, class: LogTransacao do
    codigo_transacional { codigo_transacional }
    tipo { tipos[0] }
    estornado { false }
    valor  { 0 }
    conta_origem_id { conta_origem.id }
    conta_origem_valor_antes_transacao { conta_origem.saldo }
  end
end
```

---

```
conta.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :conta do
    nome { Faker::Name.name }
    saldo { 0 }
    status { 1 }

    factory :conta_pessoa_fisica do
      pessoa_type { 'PessoaFisica' }
      pessoa_id { FactoryGirl.create(:pessoa_fisica).id }
    end
   end
 end
```

So, I'm getting the following error:

```
find': Factory not registered: pessoa_fisica
```

This problem does no occur when I use the FactoryGirl.create inside of the factory ':log_transacao_carga'.

conta_origem_id { FactoryGirl.create(:conta_pessoa_fisica).id }

However, if I do this, I cannot use the same factory to populate the 
conta_origem_valor_antes_transacao. So, I need to create this factory before the log_transacao_carga factory.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

> This problem does no occur when I use the FactoryGirl.create inside of
>   the factory ':log_transacao_carga'.

`log_transacao_carga` works because you are passing the class name to it (`LogTransacao`).

Any particular reason you are doing nested factories vs. `trait`? You can use FactoryGirl's `trait` like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :conta do
    nome { Faker::Name.name }
    saldo { 0 }
    status { 1 }

    trait :conta_pessoa_fisica do
      pessoa_type { 'PessoaFisica' }
      pessoa_id { FactoryGirl.create(:pessoa_fisica).id }
    end
   end
 end
```

and then call it with `build(:conta, :conta_pessoa_fisica`). This way it reads my better and you are able to inherit parent factory attributes and add-on / edit the ones you need in a specific context.

Check out FactoryGirl docs:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/FactoryGirl/Syntax/Methods

Here is a good intro video from the creators of FactoryGirl: https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/factory-girl

Comment: Hey, @Dimitry_N, I will check this trait. I did not use it because I have always used nested factories and it always works until before this moment.

I do not know traits, so I will try to use it. Thanks for the help.